# SSMS поддержка #region #endregion

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Коллеги подскажите пожалуйста тулы с помощью которых можно реальзовать в SSMS поддержку #region #endregion как в VS С#, ну или что-то сходное по функциональности.

Кроме:

```
BEGIN --MyRegion

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSMSBoost имеет такую фукнцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поддерживаю. Приходилось работать с SSMS. SSMSBoost удобнейшая штуковина.

Comment: "имеет такую фукнцию" - извините, а где собственно функция? В  ответе какая-то картинка.

Comment: ставите тул, находите его тулбар, надохите эту кнопку на тулбаре (можете задать хоткей через настройки студии - по-моему у меня так, т.е. это не дефолтный хоткей) - профит!)

Comment: @user3690455 дополните ответ картинками для каждого из вариантов в выпадающем списке, напишите минимальное описание, чтобы получился качественный ответ, а не просто кусочек скриншота.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам не нравится вариант с `BEGIN...END` (кстати, почему?), попробуйте [SSMS Tools Pack](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=10)

Comment: Я не написал что он мне не нравится, просто ищу другие варианты, в SSMS Tools Pack не увидел ничего нового, это все студия умеет из коробки, как мне показалось.

Comment: какая студия? VS или SSMS?

Comment: разумеется речь о SSMS, в превью Tools Pack способ с комментарием над SELECT, это и так доступно.

Comment: в данный момент не могу проверить, нахожусь за другим рабочим местом, но SSMS Tools Pack позволяет обрамлять блок кода, а не только SELECT. Попробуйте.